# Merging Git changes when the directory structure has changed

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

We have an app, the code for which is stored in a Git repository. We're using Git Flow, features are coded and then merged into the `develop` branch.

We started a major expansion for the app, adding entirely new areas of functionality. This work had its own branch created, call it `develop-new`, serving as the base for all features as normal. As part of this expansion, the directory structure was changed, and almost all the existing source files were moved.

In parallel with work on the expansion, several bug fixes were deployed to the existing app, getting merged into `develop`.

I now need to merge those bug fixes into the expansion, to ensure that everything we fixed stays fixed when we go live with the new app. I created a feature branch off `develop-new` and tried to merge `develop` into it, and ran into the problem that of course Git can't match up the changed source files in `develop` with their new locations in `develop-new`. What's the least painful way to solve this? It looks like about 16 files are affected.

Comment: I'd start by establishing the new directory structure in the develop branch.Then merge develop into develop-new.

Comment: @HeinrichHartmann Just given that a try. Unfortunately, moving the source files to the new directory structure meant that there was an edit to every moved source file that was more recent than the branch point - and that meant that the merge attempted to roll back all the changes that have been made to those files on `develop-new`.